# Magento-1.9 mage.js file issue with Google Adwords

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento and here I am facing issue with Google AdWords. 
There is a script file which is causing the issue

> https://magentocore.net/mage/mage.js

when I am running in local this script file is not coming but in the server, this file is coming in all the pages.
I checked my project but didn't find the mage.js file and have no idea where it is coming from 
Please guide me on this ...
any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known credit card scraping malware. And unfortunately, it is very successful. See [my blog](http://gwillem.gitlab.io/2018/08/30/magentocore.net_skimmer_most_aggressive_to_date/) on removal instructions for this specific skimmer.

And use [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com) or the [Magento Malware Scanner](https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner) to periodically scan your site for this kind of malicious code.

Comment: The link you posted is invalid. Can you edit it please, I'm having issues with this particular malware and despite removing it, changing logins, removing extensions etc, it keeps on coming back.

Comment: Link fixed. Hit me up if you need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

ok `Miscellaneous Scripts` are loaded on every page.

Check the miscellaneous scripts section for configuration, it should be there.

Also, don't forget to clear your Magento cache: `System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache`

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a regular file. If you can't find it in the filesystem, I would recommend checking the miscelllaneous scripts section of configuration and check the following link.

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/configuration/general/design.html